# Bing maps v8 MapTypeId does not match view

Tags: bing-maps

I have a map where I'm disabling street view so the user can't zoom in and maybe see the blue highlights allowing them to trigger street view by accident when clicking the map when zoomed in too much. However, I want them to be able to use a button on a dialogue i'm providing that will allow them to see the location at the pin if available.

My issue is I'm getting errors thrown by my code for location testing when in street view since the map stops supported tryLocationToPixel. The issue is that these sections are already guarded by the following code.

```
if(!propertyMap || propertyMap.getMapTypeId() !== Microsoft.MapTypeId.road)
    return;
```

On further inspection while visually confirming I am in street view with console.log I can tell that getMapTypeId() is still returning 'r' for road even though the view has been converted to streetview. I convert the view to street view with the following code.

```
propertyMap.setView({ center: location, streetsideOptions: { locationToLookAt: location } });
propertyMap.setMapType(Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.streetside);
```

My map is created as follows

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#compsMap',
    {
        credentials: $('#bing-key').text(),
        enableClickableLogo: false,
        enableSearchLogo: false,
        showCopyright: false,
        showDashboard: false,
        showMapTypeSelector: false,
        showScalebar: false,
        disableStreetside: true,
        streetsideOptions: { showCurrentAddress: false },
        zoom: 17
    });
```

Any way to detect the map is currently in streetview or not? Currently, I've added a try-catch to hide the error to prevent it from breaking other things but that isn't an ideal solution.

Note: maptypedchanged event doesn't work for programatically changed views either so that isn't a valid solution either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely return "r" as streetside hasn't fully loaded yet. It will not return "x" until streetside is actually visible. If streetside isn't available it will fallback to road. Because of this the map doesn't change the map type id it returns until streetside is loaded, if it loads.

That said, if you have disabled streetside, then programmatically load it, it will always return "r" as streetside is disabled. You are able to ignore this in your code and override it, but the user has no way of getting into streetside themselves. Basically, the scenario you are describing is not supported.

Comment: Yeah I simply enabled street side and will see if there are any complaints and if so just remove the feature altogether. Simpler solution, just not ideal.